# Saving context for notification in Application Android

Tags: android

I have implemented GCM Handler in my application to send a notification when it receives a message. However I have noticed that if I destroy my application by killing it in the task manager on my phone, the context variable that is passed to the method to send a notification returns null. Is there a way to save context even after the user destroys the application process to send a notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to understand where you are sending message , you should post your code 
but i will try

you will have a receiver declared in your manifest
something like this

```
  <receiver
        android:name="<PAKAGE NAME>.MyMessageReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action TAG >
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and in MyMessageReciever.java 
  A method

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
```

here is the context you don't need to save it ,use 
this context

Comment: I totally forgot about overriding on receive.  Thanks.

Comment: its okay , it happens sometime